# Is this the right way to compute covariance-matrix in parallel?

Tags: covariance

I need to compute a 600x600 covariance matrix, each factor has a sample size of 750. I have a decent cluster computers, so I am thinking about doing the calculation in parallel.

The dumb way I am thinking about is: for each two factors, create a job to compute these 2 jobs' covariance, and submit this job to the grid. Then I collect the covariances of all the pairs and then assign them into the 600x600 matrix.

Does this make sense at all?

Comment: Wait, you're computing a 600x600 covariance matrix from only a 750x600 data matrix? Are there any missing values?

Answer (score 4):

As it happens, runtime is not an issue for this problem.  Consider the following implementation using Rcpp with completely non-optimized (by me) C++ code:

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)

src <- '
void foo(NumericMatrix A, NumericMatrix B) {
  int nrows = A.nrow();
  int ncolumns = A.ncol();
  int i, j, k;
  double sum;

  for (i = 0; i < ncolumns; i++) {
    for (sum = 0, k = 0; k < nrows; k++) sum += A(k,i);
    sum /= nrows;
    for (k = 0; k < nrows; k++) A(k,i) -= sum;

    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
       for (k = 0; k < nrows; k++) {
         B(i,j) += A(k,i) * A(k,j);
       }
       B(i,j) /= nrows;
       B(j,i) = B(i,j);
     }
  }
}'

cppFunction(src)
```

Benchmarking this results in runtimes averaging about 0.2 seconds:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> x <- matrix(rnorm(750*600), 750, 600)
> y <- matrix(0,600,600)

> microbenchmark(foo(x,y), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 foo(x, y) 203.3502 204.1472 211.3426 230.9456 264.8911    10
```

And, just to show there's something in the output matrix:

```
> y[1:5,1:5]
             [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]         [,5]
[1,]  1.098348178 -0.04432606 -0.02573213 -0.01627862  0.007647209
[2,] -0.044326056  0.93672643  0.02166652 -0.03514427  0.050381680
[3,] -0.025732132  0.02166652  1.03743968 -0.03125105  0.024817283
[4,] -0.016278624 -0.03514427 -0.03125105  1.00030357 -0.016148363
[5,]  0.007647209  0.05038168  0.02481728 -0.01614836  0.942497665
```

I'm running on an Intel i7 920 CPU clocked at 2.79 GHz, 64 bit Ubuntu, 6GB memory.

As a consequence, I wouldn't bother to do it in parallel, unless you're interested in the parallelization of this particular matrix operation in its own right.

(Note also that this implementation will alter the input matrix `x`, thanks to the pass-by-reference semantics of `NumericMatrix` and the statement `A(k,i) -= sum;`).